# how can set a limit for recording video like snapchat

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using image_picker to record from the camera and my app is something like SnapChat.
but I couldn't limit the recording time on 5 seconds.
Is there any way to do that?

this link for the plugin https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

code :

```
  File _video;

  Future getVideo() async {
    var video= await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _video= video;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Take look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739629/i-use-image-picker-record-video-but-i-want-to-limit-the-time-of-the-video/54820586#54820586

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I use image\_picker record video, But I want to limit the time of the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739629/i-use-image-picker-record-video-but-i-want-to-limit-the-time-of-the-video)