# How to Stop Video Recording After some Seconds?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm recording video using image_picker. I want to stop that recording after 20seconds. Is there any way to stop recording after 20seconds.

```
 _pickVideoFromCamera() async {
    File video = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
    _cameraVideo = video;
    _cameraVideoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_cameraVideo)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _cameraVideoPlayerController.play();
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future.delayed`

```
_pickVideoFromCamera() async {
    File video = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
    _cameraVideo = video;
    _cameraVideoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_cameraVideo)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _cameraVideoPlayerController.play();
        setState(() {});
      });
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20)).then((_) { // camera stop process });
  }
```

Comment: I think i've to change package for record video. Ca't find any method to stop camera process

Comment: You have two options,

1- Fork the image_picker plugin, add timer to native codes for finish native screens. And then use your own plugin.

2- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54820586/12024114)